# how to change edittext password filed characters to star instead of dots android?

Tags: android, passwords

I created one login application with username and password fields.here my problem is when i insert the password text in edittext filed bydefault its shows in dots. I want to show it in stars symbol.Is it possible in android?
If possible please help me.

regards,
Madhu.

Answer (score 0):

You use [`setTransformationMethod()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29) and something like the [`PasswordTransformationMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html)

i.e. you make your own [PasswordTransformationMethod](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.java.htm), where instead of the DOT :

```
   private static char DOT = '\u2022';
```

You use whatever you fancy. Asterisk is `\u002A`

Comment: HI Thank u for your suggestion but am geting problem is TextKeyListener.SHOW_PASSWORD cannot be resolved