# How can I change the (.) of password to some other image dot?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a EditText which is a password field. By default android has its (.) dot which i want to replace with some image dot. How can I do that any suggestions.

Comment: try the following [link][1]. hope it'll help you.

Good Luck.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195494/how-to-change-edittext-password-filed-characters-to-star-instead-of-dots-android

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **PasswordTransformationMethod** Class [Check this Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html)

```
public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};

// Call the above class using this:
text.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: I have gone through this. here i can replace dot with *. But I want to put some Image.

Comment: i can use spannable string but i am thinking where i can add this code. I cant add it in onTextChanged()